# Windows Phone 8.1 (Not Silverlight) make app for all screen resolution

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone

I'm creating an app for Windows Phone 8.1.
How to make app for all screen resolution ?
When I was creating app for WP 8.1 Silverlight, app was automaticly resizing for different screen sizes.
And when I made app (not Silverlight) for 5 inch display and when I run it on 4,5 inch display the app was out of display.
Can you give me some advice what I'm doing wrong ?